# Declaring a higher order function in Typescript with optional argument

Tags: typescript

I am trying to declare the type of a higher order function that can take at most 1 argument.

I should be able to supply a function to my class that takes either 0 or 1 argument. My current try is this:

```js
type FunctionWithOptionalStringArg = ((x?: string) => void)

class Logger {
    logger: FunctionWithOptionalStringArg
    constructor(logger: FunctionWithOptionalStringArg){
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    log = (x?: string) => {
        this.logger(x)
    }

}

const logString = (x: string) => console.log(x)
const logDate = () => console.log(Date.now());

const stringLogger = new Logger(logString) //Error
const dateLogger = new Logger(logDate)
```

However, declaring the `stringLogger` returns an error because my class doesn't accept a function that always takes a string argument.

How should I declare my type?

Comment: Have you already tried to set a default value? `((x: string = '') => void)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really [don't](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#optional-parameters-in-callbacks) want to make the `x` parameter optional.  Inside your `Logger` class you are going to pass a `string` argument into the `logger` callback.

What you're trying to say is that the `logger` callback should feel free to *ignore* that `string` parameter if it wants.  And this is automatically supported.  So, instead of making the parameter optional, just declare that the function accepts a single `string` parameter.  A zero-arg function is considered [compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) with that also, because it is (usually) safe to call a function with extra arguments because such a function will just ignore them.

See [the FAQ entry on extra function arguments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) for more information.

So that means you should change your code to something like:

```
type FunctionAcceptingStringArg = ((x: string) => void)

class Logger {
  logger: FunctionAcceptingStringArg
  constructor(logger: FunctionAcceptingStringArg) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  log = (x: string) => {
    this.logger(x)
  }

}
```

I also changed `log` to require a `string` argument.  Bad things can happen if you actually call `logger()` with `undefined` for its argument, since `logger` might be `(x: string) => console.log(x.toUpperCase())` which would give a runtime error in such cases.  It is far more likely that you will always call `logger` with a `string` argument than it is for you to want an optional argument.

---

Now you can verify that it works as desired:

```
const logString = (x: string) => console.log(x.toUpperCase())
const logDate = () => console.log(Date.now());
const logStuff = (x: string, y: number) => console.log(x.toUpperCase() + y.toFixed(2))

const stringLogger = new Logger(logString) // okay
const dateLogger = new Logger(logDate) // okay
const nope = new Logger(logStuff); // error!  
// -------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '(x: string, y: number) => void' is not assignable to
// parameter of type 'FunctionAcceptingStringArg'
```

The `logString` and `logDate` callbacks are accepted, since each of them are safe to call with just a `string` argument.  But `logStuff` is rejected because it requires a second argument that will not be passed in.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEEElImNBAcwGVgAnVYrcoqAXigAomAPALigGcKqiBKBgD4oAN3SoAJvwBQMpABsAhly5QAMuiJEI5KAG8ZUKAq07yneMjSYceAnzKVqtI1CSYe5OCnTkmptq6logoGNi4+ISkvC4CBm7GwAAWqFwAdIHmDCZmugDcbgC+csaBOWycXnyC9CKGxkmpGVm6bLLGJTJd8p7AuTHOdIyV3LHxde6e6AoQmVps6cDoAKpgkOQAwioQTPyyHgg8AwAiSsDQI7Uih1wzc4FMZxfpCOgA7nv8hbf9gWRwABmgIqHDGQwANFAQJwEHAALYAI101ymR3u8yIi2Waw22y4u0EAGpoUt0DBUKwIJImAAmfZyX7gviaIJ6RgICDvDR5fz-caCAD0gqg6AA1koQL0jv1JOcIKzshyuTy2QEtM8IEKReLJdLjm9IDlOdzFW1+UDAd8oMKoLpyH4AITGGS2mhEBEQBD9dAg0BGgDko2qxChMKgcKRKOEYgkkgDUDSEfQ-VdIpUXFQRAQSkRsygyygYCU5CU8IgFz0voL4GgAasYVskQcxCcfHdUADQA)